# Next js(14) is requesting for assets on each request

Tags: next.js, primereact, app-router, app-themes

I have started with Next.js 14(App Router). I am using a component library PrimeReact, using this library i have to switch themes. Now in primeReact if I have to switch themes for that it have different css files for each theme. Here is how my theme.css files are placed in my folder.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51HzN.png)

and this is my root layout.tsx file which wraps the entire app

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Roboto } from "next/font/google";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import "./globals.css";
import { PrimeReactProvider } from "primereact/api";
import Tailwind from "primereact/passthrough/tailwind";
import { appColorScheme } from "@/lib/constants";
import { getSiteSettings } from "@/lib/api-service/siteSettings";
import { SiteSettings } from "@/types/api-service";
import AppWrapper from "@/components/AppWrapper";

const RobotoFont = Roboto({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  weight: ["500", "700", "900"],
  variable: "--font-roboto"
});

const PoppinsLocalFont = localFont({
  src: "../lib/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2",
  variable: "--font-poppins"
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app"
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const siteData: SiteSettings = await getSiteSettings();
  const appTheme = siteData
    ? siteData?.color_scheme.value
    : appColorScheme[0]?.value;

  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      className={`${RobotoFont.variable} ${PoppinsLocalFont.variable}`}
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      <PrimeReactProvider value={{ unstyled: false, pt: Tailwind }}>
       ` <head>
          <link
            id="theme-link"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href={`/${appTheme}/theme.css`}
          />
        </head>`
        <body>
          <AppWrapper>{children}</AppWrapper>
        </body>
      </PrimeReactProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Every time when I switch theme   `` <head> <link  id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href={`/${appTheme}/theme.css`} /> </head> `` relevent theme.css files is downloaded from server. Is there a way I can store these css files on client side so theme can change smoothly without making a http request?

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxi1l.png)

Changing themes in next.js 14 using primereact